# Azure change CloudBlockBob URL to be different than name

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have this code that uploads my images

```
        var blobClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobName);

        // Create a unique name for the images we are about to upload
        var file = String.Format("{0}-{1}{2}", fileName, Guid.NewGuid(), Path.GetExtension(fileToUpload.FileName));

        // Upload image to Blob Storage
        var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file);
        blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = fileToUpload.ContentType;
        await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileToUpload.InputStream);

        fullPath = blockBlob.Uri.ToString();
```

Now in blob I Have this info **Name**: test+GUID / **URL**: test+GUID
[image]

How can I save in blob **Name**: test / **URL**: GUID ,  so name in URL will not be displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not work that way to have the blob name different from URL. It is some thing like your windows path which will resemble your file name and where these two cannot be different.

But considering your requirements, use only GUID in the blob name and url so that the actual name of file is hidden from URL. And try to use Blob Metadata for storing and getting the actual name.

```
// Get a reference to a blob.
CloudBlob blob = blobClient.GetBlobReference("mycontainer/myblob.txt");

// Populate the blob's attributes.
blob.FetchAttributes();

// Enumerate the blob's metadata.
foreach (var metadataKey in blob.Metadata.Keys)
{
Console.WriteLine("Metadata name: " + metadataKey.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Metadata value: " +        
blob.Metadata.Get(metadataKey.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: I'm using dev blob now, and for "blob.FetchAttributes();" getting exception  The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.    because I'm usign dev blob?

Comment: There is no such limitation on dev and it should work fine on dev emulator as well. 404 Not Found - means blob does not exist or If it is a block blob there might be uncommitted blocks. Make sure that your block blob is fully saved by calling PutBlockList(blocklistIds) method. For ref - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/windows-azure-blockblob-putblock-method/